# Preg_match over multiple lines

Tags: regex, preg-match

My code is **sometimes** split over two lines like so:

[image]

I'm trying to match part of the URL by using the following regex:

```
https://www.url.com/(.*?)">Please Click Here
```

I have tried using `/s` and `/m` on the line but doesn't seem to match.

Any advice?

Comment: Which is the part you'r are supposed to match?

Comment: An advice: Pasting your string instead of pasting an image of your string will be a great idea.

Comment: seems like a pretty niche thing to want to match, how many instances of 'Please Click Here' do you have :o

Comment: Please don't use images if you can avoid it.  You'll get more and better solutions if you provide us with code that we can paste into our own editors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that "Please Click Here" won't match this:

```
Please Click
Here
```

The latter contains whitespace characters like `\n`, `\r` (maybe), and possibly `\t`.  Although it doesn't look like it contains `\t` from the image you posted, it's better to try to handle that scenario, too.  The `\s` expression will catch a simple space (), as well as each of these characters.

Use this regex instead:

```
https://www\.url\.com/(?:[^"]*)(?=">Please\s+Click\s+Here)
```

Edit: tweaked further to return only the URL, not "Please Click Here" and the `">`.

Comment: You can remove the `(?s)`. However +1

Comment: Dot `.` match anything in regex!

Answer (score 1):

For static url, basic search pattern would be:

```
/https:\/\/www\.url\.com\/([^\"]*)\"[^>]*>\s*Please\s+Click\s+Here/
```

But you better use `$url` as a variable and include it in regex pattern as follow:

```
/<a\b[^>]*\burl=\"$url\"[^>]*>\s*Please\s+Click\s+Here\s*<\/a>/i
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the `s` (single line) or `m` (multi-line) modifier here.

You could use something as simple as the following.

```
preg_match('~([^/]+)(?=">please\s+click\s+here)~i', $text, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

The `i` modifier is used for case-insensitive matching.

See [`live demo`](https://eval.in/69172)